# Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)' sytax error (missing operatory) in SQL query expression in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am building SQL queries in VBA, and the following returns an error:

```
stSQLstring = "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "$]
               WHERE [" & headerName & "] in (" & stNodes & ");"
```

Debug.Print stSQLstring gives:

```
SELECT * FROM [sheetName$]
WHERE [headerName] in ('3','4','5','6','16','45','64','65','67','71','76','79','80','86','89','103','115','116','124','142','145','160');
```

I am then using ACE.OLEDB to query an external workbook (I think this part is fine as it works with other SQL statements, just not this one).

I would be really grateful for you help!

Comment: And the error is...?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the single quotes when working with numbers.

```
SELECT * FROM [sheetName$] WHERE [headerName] in (3,4,5,6,16,45,64,65,67,71,76,79,80,86,89,103,115,116,124,142,145,160);
```

Comment: This is true except if the numbers are stored in cells which are formatted as Text. But this seems not the case here because it would work then with numbers in single quotes.

Comment: @Amy Rollinson: Fine. But you should nevertheless mention what the error was. I suspect "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". Please mention the error in your question through editing it. It will then be more useful for other users.